# How to render Latex in Jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook, latex, jupyter, jupyter-lab

So I am trying to get Latex in my Jupyter Lab going.

If I insert this

```
\begin{eqnarray}
     y & = & ax^2 + bx + c \\
     f(x) & = & x^2 + 2xy + y^2
\end{eqnarray}
```

it gets rendered as expected

But

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item First.
    \item Second.
\end{itemize}
```

gets rendered as the text

[image]

I already installed @jupyterlab/latex extension